# Complement of open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have the following connected real intervals:
$$ T=[0,10] ~~,~~ A=[0,1) ~~,~~   B= (3,7)    ~~,~~ C = (9,10)    $$

and also a set
$$F=T\setminus \{A\cup B\cup C\}$$

We have the definition, "A set is closed if it is the complement of an open set."  My question regards $A$ including its boundary point at zero.  Is the set $\{A\cup B\cup C\}$ open in the sense that its complement $F$ in $T$ is closed?  Thanks.

Comment: It is important to specify whether you are using the usual topology for the whole real line, or the subspace topology induced by it on T.

Comment: What would be the distinction of the two cases?

Comment: In the subspace topology A is an open set.

Comment: Thanks, Ali!  You are a cool guy.

Answer (score 1):

$A\cup B\cup C$ It is not closed since $1$ ($1=lim_n1-{1\over n}$, $n$ a non zero integer) is a limit point which is not contained in it, so $T-\{A\cup B\cup C\}$ is not open.

Comment: What about my question about "A set is closed if it is the complement of an open set."   My question is about $F$.  Thanks!